# How configure aws-ec2 Instance to run playframework 1.2.7 application

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, playframework, ubuntu-14.04

I have deployed our playframework 1.2.7 web application to aws-ec2 ubuntu instance. The started the application on port 8081 since 80 or 8080 complains about not able to bind to those ports. How can I configure the ubuntu instance either througth the aws security group or on ubuntu itself so that I wouldn't have to add the port 8081 to the end of the public url or the public ip provided by aws.
ie I don't want do this:

```
example.com:8081 / ip4:8081
```

But I just want to use:

```
example.com / ip4
```

to access the application.
Please I need help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that on Ubuntu ports < 1024 are privileged. This means that normal users can do nothing with it. To start play on port 80 you could simply start it as **root** user. **Anyway it's not a best practice to start webserver as root due to possible security issues.**

I'd suggest to start it on whatever non-privileged port you want, as normal user, and **make use of an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) to redirect all inbound traffic on port 80(or 443 for instance) to your play port**. You can accomplish this simply using AWS web interface, when creating an ELB

So users will reach your play instance calling ELB on port 80 using Amazon auto-assigned dns name.

**Example flow:**
User browser --> http://your-elb-dns-name.com --> your_play_server_ip:8081

**Just make sure that the Security Group** associated to your play server instance will accept inbound traffic on 8081 from your ELB (you can identify your ELB using the amazon id assigned during its creation)

Another great advantage of using this ELB approach is that you can use it as **reverse proxy to hide your ec2-instance(s) ip(s) to the internet**. In fact, if you use ELB you could also avoid assignin a public ip to your ec2 instance during creation. ELB doesn't need to know a public ip beacuse it will have access to the **Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)** in which your ec2 instance was started

Another possible approach, if you don't want to use ELB, is to install NGINx or Apache on your ec2 instance to act as reverse proxy, but I think you should make use of Amazon web services to accomplish that. You may want to use an internal NGINX or Apache reverse proxy if you need to hide a particular resource of your play server to the internet.

https://aws.amazon.com/it/elasticloadbalancing/

Comment: Thanks very much **Andrea** for the education, it really solved the issue.